I neеd hеlp with a WordPress project
WordPress is installed in the root of the site. I can't log in to my uploaded file, I find myself on page 404. For example, I upload a new folder to the site, which is separate from WordPress index.php.
How do I access it? I want my index.php my catalog was opened via the page URL and I did not get to the 404 WordPress page.
I am grateful in advance.
WordPress Version 6.5.5, Nginx Server

i need more info but i think you have rewrite issue.
use this in nginx config:
location /
{
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

